# Reliable cross-browser info on ContentEditable

Tags: html, cross-browser, contenteditable

I am looking for a list of web browsers that fully support using ContentEditable. I know that I.E has supported it since 5 or 5.5, but what about other browsers. I know that the modern versions of Chrome, Flock, Maxthon, Opera and I.E support it. But I don't care about the modern browsers. What about the older versions of them, like I.E 6/7/8, Safari,  Firefox, Avast, etc etc?

I can't find any useful information on this. Does anybody know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [**The WHATWG blog**](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable) provides reliable information, but not of all browsers:

  > Firefox 3, Safari 3, Opera 9, Google Chrome, and Internet Explorer (since 5.5)
- [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable) also gives you a good table, (again, only for popular browsers)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Checking the link now. That's more than enough information for me to make a decision :)

Answer (score 4):

`contenteditable` is already supported by major browsers. The problem is `execCommand` command, of course, the devil is in the details.

Detail compatibility: http://tifftiff.de/contenteditable/compliance_test.html

Answer (score 0):

Table with browsers support :

http://caniuse.com/contenteditable