# html / css how to Middle (vertically) align text inside a <textarea>

Tags: html, css

I want to centre the text inside a text area; I am trying with the line height, but it doesn't work.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you trying to vertical-align multi-line text in a textarea? You can't. If you are talking about single-line text, I can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `contenteditable="true"` attribute on a `<div>` and then skin it with CSS.

Here is a link for cross browser compatibility: [Reliable cross-browser info on ContentEditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052102/reliable-cross-browser-info-on-contenteditable)

Answer (score 2):

You can use padding only to achieve that, but it's not pretty way to do things. You can also use jQuery to make the padding flexible, instead of just setting it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Hey now you can used input tag

Replace textarea into input tag as like this

and define `height` and `line-height`

**Css**

```
input[type="text"]{
line-height:125px;
    height:125px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/MTCrt/

Comment: but that is not multiline